# Format of file to be uploaded to Autodesk Forge

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk-model-derivative

Im following the tutorial on the autodesk website
https://forge.autodesk.com/developer/idea/viewer-app

and also

https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/tutorials/prep-file4viewer/task2-upload_source_file_to_oss/

and im able to authenticate, create the bucket and it appears i can also upload my file.

Im uploading a .rvt file but the issue arises when ping the status endpoint to check the status of the file conversion to .svf format so i can make use of the file in the viewer.

The error its returning is

name : LMV Bubble
progress : complete
Messages :
Tr worker fail to download.
TranslationWorker-InternalFailure
Output Type : svf
status : failed

This then results in an error code in the viewer library as there appears to be no file
onDocumentLoadFailure() - errorCode:9

Ive followed the tutorials to the letter multiple times over and all appears process except this part.

Ive tried making use of different rvt files, zip files and nothing appears to work.

```
    <cffunction name="convertFile" access="public" returntype="any" description="I convert a file for autodesk">
    <cfargument name="token" type="string" required="true">
    <cfargument name="urn" type="string" required="false" default="">
    <cfargument name="filename" type="string" required="true">

<cfoutput>
<cfsavecontent variable="jsonstring">
{
"input": {
"urn": "#toBase64(arguments.urn)#",
"rootFilename": "#arguments.filename#",
"compressedUrn": true
},"output": {
"destination": {
"region": "us"
},"formats": [
{"type": "svf",
"views": [
"2d",
"3d"]}]}}
</cfsavecontent>
</cfoutput>

        <cfhttp url="https://developer.api.autodesk.com/modelderivative/v2/designdata/job" method="post">
            <cfhttpparam type="header" name="Authorization" value="Bearer #arguments.token#">
            <cfhttpparam type="header" name="Content-Type" value="application/json">
            <cfhttpparam type="body" value="#trim(jsonstring)#">                
        </cfhttp>
        <cfset var returnObj = {}>
        <cfif isJSON(cfhttp.filecontent)>
            <cfset returnObj = deserializeJSON(cfhttp.filecontent)>
        </cfif>
        <cfreturn returnObj>        
    </cffunction>
```

Comment: Could you share your request body of https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/tutorials/prep-roominfo4viewer/option1/#step-1-start-a-translation-job?

Comment: Meanwhile, could you try my postman scripts here: https://github.com/yiskang/forge.api.postman

Comment: we are simply posting the data across using lucee. - please see code snippet in original post

Comment: Sorry, I'm not familiar with lucee. But if you're uploading a single RVT file for translation, the value of `compressedUrn` should be `false`. Otherwise, the translation will fail. BTW, to override failed translation results, you need to add an extra request header `x-ads-force: true`, if the urn doesn't change.

Comment: Thank you very much, the swapping of compressUrn to false and x-ads-force = true solved the issue and i can now render the files.

Comment: Nice, thank you for sharing the good news 

Answer (score 0):

For a single RVT translation, the value of `compressedUrn` should be false. Otherwise, the translation will fail.

```sh
curl --location --request POST 'https://developer.api.autodesk.com/modelderivative/v2/designdata/job' \
--header 'Authorization: Bearer {{YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN}}' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data'{
   "input": {
     "urn": "dXJuOmFkc2sub2JqZWN0czpvcy5vYmplY3Q6WU9VUl9CVUNLRVRfS0VZL3JtZV9hZHZhbmNlZF9zYW1wbGVfcHJvamVjdC5ydnQ" //!<<< e.g., base64 encoded URN: urn:adsk.objects:os.object:YOUR_BUCKET_KEY/rme_advanced_sample_project.rvt
   },
   "output": {
     "formats": [
       {
         "type": "svf",
         "views": [
           "2d",
           "3d"
         ]
       }
     ]
   }
 }'
```

Instead, for a composite RVT model (a ZIP file containing host RVT and linked RVTs), the value of `compressedUrn` should be true, and the `rootFilename` should be specified to the host RVT file name. For example, you have a composite RVT model named as `sample-buidling.zip`. It contains the host RVT (`sample-arch.rvt`) and a linked RVT (`sample-str.rvt`)

```sh
curl --location --request POST 'https://developer.api.autodesk.com/modelderivative/v2/designdata/job' \
--header 'Authorization: Bearer {{YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN}}' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data'{
   "input": {
     "urn": "dXJuOmFkc2sub2JqZWN0czpvcy5vYmplY3Q6WU9VUl9CVUNLRVRfS0VZL3NhbXBsZS1idWlkbGluZy56aXA" //!<<< e.g., base64 encoded URN: urn:adsk.objects:os.object:YOUR_BUCKET_KEY/sample-buidling.zip,
     "rootFilename": "sample-arch.rvt",
     "compressedUrn": true
   },
   "output": {
     "formats": [
       {
         "type": "svf",
         "views": [
           "2d",
           "3d"
         ]
       }
     ]
   }
 }'
```

If the translation failed or you want to override the existed translated result by uploading an updated file without changing the URN, we need to upload the file with OAuth scope `data:write` add an extra request header `x-ads-force: true` while calling POST job like this:

```sh
curl --location --request POST 'https://developer.api.autodesk.com/modelderivative/v2/designdata/job' \
--header 'Authorization: Bearer {{YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN}}' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--header 'x-ads-force: true' \
--data'{
   "input": {
     "urn": "dXJuOmFkc2sub2JqZWN0czpvcy5vYmplY3Q6WU9VUl9CVUNLRVRfS0VZL3JtZV9hZHZhbmNlZF9zYW1wbGVfcHJvamVjdC5ydnQ" //!<<< e.g., base64 encoded URN: urn:adsk.objects:os.object:YOUR_BUCKET_KEY/rme_advanced_sample_project.rvt
   },
   "output": {
     "formats": [
       {
         "type": "svf",
         "views": [
           "2d",
           "3d"
         ]
       }
     ]
   }
 }'
```